# LAMP stack everything seems to be working except sites are blank

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, mysql, php, lamp

I have a LAMP stack,

- Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS
- PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.8 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Sep  4 2013 20:05:42)
- Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
- MYSQL 5.5.32-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 (Ubuntu)
- Codeigniter 2.1.0

All of these are currently running as they should be.

The sites are:

- [bf.getsimpleapps.com](http://bf.getsimpleapps.com)
- [ac.getsimpleapps.com](http://ac.getsimpleapps.com)
- [getsimpleapps.com](http://getsimpleapps.com)

Some load with a blank white page others with a 500 Server Error.

How do I go about debugging as to why it's not working. The PHP sites / code should be running fine, the code has been in production for months.

This all started because I went into the server today to make clear some disk space (I deleted some `mysqldump`s). I also ran `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` and it might have updated PHP. Now that mysql is working I assumed that was the main bug, but now these sites are unresponsive.

I've already checked the individual site error logs and there's nothing in them. I've tried to enable PHP error reporting to see if that's the issue and nothing is coming up. I've replaced a sites `/public` directory with a "hello world" `index.php` file and it came up on the site just fine, which means the server is working as it should, right?

Any assistance would be really great, I'm totally dead in the water...

Comment: What about logs? Syslog, apache logs etc.

Comment: That is not blank. Your PHP source is clearly visible there.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'm seeing nothing at all on those sites, rendered or in view-source. You're seeing PHP source? Can you take a screenshot?

Comment: @strangeman I've checked the sites apache logs and there's nothing in them. Where can I find `Syslog`?

Comment: @ThomasReggi /var/log/syslog 
Hmm. '500 Server Error' must record error in the log too.

Comment: @strangeman nothing apache related in there

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough information to debug the first two, but the last link is missing a proper php start tag. You are using "<php" instead of "<?php"

See this link for more information:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

As for debugging the first two, I would start by inspecting the error log file for the web server. Usually, I find those are located in a place like "/var/log".

Here's the responses from your server. I used a traffic inspector application to get this data.

```
bf.getsimpleapps.com

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 24 Sep 2013 00:47:28 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 26
Content-Type: text/html

ac.getsimpleapps.com

HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Tue, 24 Sep 2013 00:47:45 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 26
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

getsimpleapps.com

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 24 Sep 2013 00:48:05 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.8
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 2252
Content-Type: text/html
```

<php

... your raw source code omitted for security reasons ...

Comment: Using `<php` instead of `<?php` is almost certainly the cause of the problems.

Comment: I was debugging and did `<php` in `vim` by accident after there was already an issue. I don't know how you are seeing raw code because I can't in chrome. I just fixed it and everything is still down. Any other ideas?

Comment: When the tag is malformed, the entire page is treated as text and dumped to client. Your browser may have hidden this from you, but it was very clear when I inspected the traffic. The response on "getsimpleapps.com" is now similar to the "bf" and "ac" servers. Now, you should examine your error logs on the server. For Ubuntu and Apache2, check the files in this directory "/var/log/apache2". Look for a file named "error.log".

Comment: Any other ideas not that that is fixed?

Comment: When you're done checking out your server's error.log file, you can head over to this discussion to get ideas on how to enable PHP's fancy debugging features. Just stick your directives right after your php start tag. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php